# Login Script Variables - Read from a text file

Tags: variables, vbscript

I have a simple login script that I use to map drives for users

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")

Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives

For i = 0 to colDrives.Count-1 Step 2
    objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive colDrives.Item(i)
Next

Dim Network
Set Network = CreateObject("Wscript.network")

Network.MapNetworkDrive "P:","\\server-A\share name A"
Network.MapNetworkDrive "N:","\\server-A\share name B"
Network.MapNetworkDrive "S:","\\server-A\share name C"
Network.MapNetworkDrive "L:","\\server-B\share name A"
Network.MapNetworkDrive "T:","\\server-C\share name"
Network.MapNetworkDrive "V:","\\server-B\share name B"
Network.MapNetworkDrive "W:","\\server-D\share name"
```

I would like to put the

```
"\\server-A\share name A"
"\\server-A\share name B"
"\\server-A\share name C"
"\\server-B\share name A"
"\\server-C\share name"
"\\server-B\share name B"
"\\server-D\share name"
```

In a text file and have my script read it and insert it into the script. Can anyone help with how to do this?

Comment: Creating the second `Wscript.Network` instance isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Const SharesFile = "C:\Test\shares.txt"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set colDrives = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
For i = 0 to colDrives.Count -1 Step 2
    objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive colDrives.Item(i)
Next
Set objTxtStream = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(SharesFile, 1, False, -2) ' charset: -2 = System default, -1 = Unicode, 0 = ASCII
For Each strLetter In Array("P:", "N:", "S:", "L:", "T:", "V:", "W:")
    If objTxtStream.AtEndOfStream Then Exit For
    objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strLetter, objTxtStream.ReadLine
Next
```

The `shares.txt` text file content should be without quotes:

```
\\server-A\share name A
\\server-A\share name B
\\server-A\share name C
\\server-B\share name A
\\server-C\share name
\\server-B\share name B
\\server-D\share name
```